# FFMPEG. Concatenate videos with a intro and music

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge videos with an intro and a background music.

The intro.flv is a short file with video and audio.
The other videos are without audio.
ambientmusic.mp3 is audio to add to subsequent videos.
A short fade for each file.

```
ffmpeg -i intro.flv -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i ambientmusic.mp3 -filter_complex "[0] fade = in: 0: 25 [v0]; [1] fade = in: 0:25 [v1]; [2] fade = in: 0: 25 [v2]; [3] fade = in: 0: 25 [v3]; [v0] [v1] [v2] [v3] concat = 4 [v] "-map" [v] "-map a ./output/final.mp4
```

Unfortunately the code only loads the first audio. Same result as

```
-map 0: a
```

If I use this instead it loads ambientmusic.mp3 on the whole video.

```
-map 4: a
```

But I'd like the audio of the Intro followed by the ambientmusic.mp3

```
-map 0: a -map 4: a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the audio in [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) and mix it with [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix):

```
ffmpeg -i intro.flv -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i ambientmusic.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]fade=in:0:25[v0];[1]fade=in:0:25[v1];[2]fade=in:0:25[v2];[3]fade=in:0:25[v3];[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[v];[0:a][4:a]amix[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -shortest ./output/final.mp4
```

You may have to add the `-t` option before `ambientmusic.mp3`, or do some other workaround, due to a [bug with `-shortest`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3789). Value for `-t` should equal duration of output.